# Would a not used first-time UK Visa on my passport cause any problems?

Tags: visas, uk

I have secured a standard 6 months UK Visa, but due to some change in plans, I might not be travelling this time.

Would this be a problem when applying again for any Visa, specially that it is the first Visa on my passport?
And if so, is there any procedure that I should follow to prevent those problems?

Finally, I know that UK visa usually gives some weight to the passport, and helps in issuing other visas in future, would this still be the case in case of a not used one?

Comment: This is no problem at all. If anything, it indicates that you didn’t get the visa just to get to the U.K. without any intention to return.